# Why spacy need start and end position in tagging annotation

Tags: spacy

I was training spacy name entity recognition with my custom dataset.
One question stick in my mind, why spacy need start and end position of tag in annotation?

```py
[
    ('I want apples', {'entities': [(2, 5, 'COMMAND'), (7, 12, 'FRUIT')]})
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because named entities are allowed to span several tokens, for instance:

```
("Who is Shaka Khan?", {"entities": [(7, 17, "PERSON")]}),
```

"Shaka Khan" would be one entity with the label PERSON.

Instead, if you would annotate

```
("Who is Shaka Khan?", {"entities": [(7, 12, "PERSON")]}),
```

then only "Shaka" would be the tagged entity.

Comment: Hi @sofie-vl
thank you so much. Nice explanation. 
I was finding difference between traditional entity tagging dataset with spacy dataset. 
traditional sequence tagging dataset contains only word,tag format. 
Thanks again. 
regards